# Git merge - update both feature and master

Tags: git, git-merge

On my Git repository, I have a feature branch and a master branch. I want to merge the two. For convenicence, however, I would like to keep the feature branch and contiune development of the feature without creating a new branch. That is, I would like to have the following structure:

```
Master     M0 --- M1 --- M2 --- M3 --- M4
            \                  /  \
Feature      F0 ---- F1 ---- F2    F3 --- F4
```

The recent state `F4` of the feature branch shall include all changes to master up to state `M3`.

My understanding was that `git merge` would do exactly this. However, after trying this out another time, I receive the message that the feature branch is a couple commits behind the master branch. Is this expected or is there an error somewhere? If this is the expected behaviour, how do I achieve what I want?

Comment: Your graphics shows exactly what `git merge` does. What exactly is the desired result? Of course feature branch will run behind master since M1 and M2 happened on master but not feature. However that should not be a problem for merging.

Comment: @mousetail I want that M1 and M2 are included in F3. If this were what `git merge` does, this would answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge master into the feature branch first:

```
$ git switch feature
$ git merge master # Apply all changes in master to feature
$ # (At this step, you might want to do some testing to make sure the merge didn't cause any new bugs)
$ git switch master
$ git merge feature # Apply all changes in the feature branch back to master
```

In fact, you should *always* merge master into any other branch before merging the result back into master. This way you can correct any merge conflicts in your feature branch while making sure master always stays functional.

Answer (score 0):

Just take hash of M2 commit and execute commands:

```
git switch featureBranch
git merge hash-of-master-commit-I-want_to-merge
```

**Answering to comment**

To get hash of a commit execute following:

```
git switch master # switch to master branch
git log -10 # view last 10 commits
```

Example outpput for one commit:

```
commit 667c0a6e4e40f10d3b86178eb51b209aa73ccf67
Author: Michal Turczyn <my@email.com>
Date:   Wed Jan 13 15:03:54 2021 +0100

    MASTER Added 2nd method
```

First line contains hash of a commit. Use it with merge command:

```
git switch featureBranch
git merge 667c0a6e4e40f10d3b86178eb51b209aa73ccf67
```

This will merge `maaster` commits up to specified commit. Just as you want.

Comment: I am sorry; I do not understand what is happening here. Do you have a reference with further information?